# How to know when the yoyo will finish?

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I want show a `trace("test")` at the end of the yoyo

How to know when the yoyo will finish?

I'm using AS3

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(my_mc, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 100,300, 1, true);

myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
    myTween.yoyo();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(my_mc, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 100,300, 1, true);
myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
var yoyoCounter:uint;

function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
    if(yoyoCounter < 1)
    {
        myTween.yoyo();
        ++yoyoCounter;
    }
    else
    {
        myTween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
        trace("test");
    }
}
```

Rob